# In EntityFramework how do you search for a property that may or may not be null

Tags: entity-framework, null

I am trying to find a single statement that will work for the query below. 
I can query for nulls or integer values but not both with the same code.

[image]

[image]

```
  int? age = null;

  Student student;

  age = 12;

  //works
  student = entities.Students.Single(s => s.Age == age);

  //does not work - crash
  student = entities.Students.Single(s => s.Age.Equals(age));

  age = null;
  //works
  student = entities.Students.Single(s => s.Age.Equals(age));
```

Note in response to the first answer:

```
//crashes with error - sequence contains no elements
age = null;
student = entities.Students.Single(s => s.Age == age);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is [well known and reported issue](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl). The workaround is:

```
student = entities.Students.Single(s => age == null ? s.Age == null : s.Age == age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student = entities.Students.Single(s => s.Age == age);
```

That one should meet your requirements, checks for equality on null value and the value itself.